Regarding backup of Ubuntu account
I have deleted my Ubuntu account. But now I want to restore it. I have deleted it using the userdel command.
How can I get back my account?
I did not use any options like -r --remove.

Did you use plain userdel, or did you pass any options? If you didn't add the -r, --remove option then the user's home directory should be intact.

If you passed the -r flag immediately stop using the computer to prevent corruption to already deleted files as much as possible and look up how to undelete files using testdisk (it should work for ext4 IIRC)

I didn't pass any options ,By the way I was using Oracle virtualbox .

If you didn't pass the -r flag, all you need to do should be to add the user back as explained in the second part of the linked answer (adduser), let us know how that works for you
